# Узнать количество записей в таблице MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно с помощью PHP узнать сколько в таблице users пользователей, у которых значение rating больше 10. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Если нужно узнать только количество строк, но не нужны сами строки

Для того чтобы узнать количество записей в таблице, нужно использовать SQL функцию `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users
```

Если нужно подсчитать количество записей по условию, то его надо добавить в запрос:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE rating > 10
```

Для получения этого значения в РНР можно выполнить запрос обычным порядком

```
$res = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE rating > 10");
$row = $res->fetch_row();
$count = $row[0];
```

Если условие задается динамически, то при запросе необходимо использовать подготовленные выражения:

```
$rating = 10;
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE rating > ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $rating);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $res->fetch_row();
$count = $row[0];
```

#### Если нужно получить сами строки, а также узнать, сколько их

Здесь ещё проще. Просто получаем все строки в массив:

```
$res = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE rating > 10");
$rows = $res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Здесь мы получили обычный массив, с которым можем делать то же самое что и с любым другим массивом. например, если нам надо узнать есть ли в массиве что-нибудь, мы можем подставить его в прямо в условие:

```
if (!$rows) {
    echo "ничего не нашлось";
} else {
    foreach ($rows as $row ) {
        echo $row['name'];
    }
}
```

Если вдруг надо получить именно количество строк, то просто выполняем обычную функцию `count()`